# How do I use a list string of comma separated variables to function arguments in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings which contain the arguments to a class constructor. I need to convert the list of strings into a list of CallDetail objects. The list has to be created in a class called Util

```
class CallDetail:
    def __init__(self, phoneno, called_no, duration, call_type):
        self.__phoneno=phoneno
        self.__called_no=called_no
        self.__duration=duration
        self.__call_type=call_type

call='9990000001,9330000001,23,STD'
call2='9990000001,9330000002,54,Local'
call3='9990000001,9330000003,6,ISD'

list_of_call_string=[call,call2,call3]
```

I have tried this----

```
class Util:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_call_objects=None

    def parse_customer(self,list_of_call_string):
        for i in range(0,3):
            info=list_of_call_string[i].split(",")
            ob=CallDetail(info[0],info[1],info[2],info[3])
            self.list_of_call_objects.append(ob)
        pass
```

This isn't working because we cannot append 'NoneType'

Comment: you need to instantiate with an empty list `self.list_of_call_objects=[]` and not `None`

Comment: Is there any other way? @DeveshKumarSingh.  This was helpful but i have "structural test cases" and if I don't use None i do not pass all of the test cases.

Comment: not sure what "structural test cases" are? also what test cases won't pass?

Comment: I'm not supposed to change the structure of the Class Util, as in I am not supposed to change         " self.list_of_call_objects=None". Since I'm changing it in this scenario, one Test case won't pass

Comment: @Ankita You can change `self.list_of_call_objects` in your `parse_customer` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `self.list_of_call_objects` to `list` type not keep it `none`

```
class Util:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_call_objects=[]
```

this will solve your problem.

As going through comment OP dont want to change type in `Util` class then , 
he can change it's type in function calling

```
class Util:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_call_objects=None

    def parse_customer(self,list_of_call_string):
        self.list_of_call_objects = list()
        for i in range(0,3):
            info=list_of_call_string[i].split(",")
            ob=CallDetail(info[0],info[1],info[2],info[3])
            self.list_of_call_objects.append(ob)
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution.

```
def parse_customer(self, list_of_call_string):
   self.list_of_call_objects = [CallDetail(*info.split(',')) for info in list_of_call_string]
```